# Adding new components/content to existing application

Tags: jss

I'm still pretty new to JSS/Sitecore and am trying to wrap my head around some of the concepts. One thing I don't understand is if its possible to create new layouts/templates on an existing app and deploy just the content of the new layouts/templates while not overwriting the existing content on the old layouts/templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the default, deploy will not override templates or layouts imported previously (unless used with `-w` option). You can also try:

- `jss deploy template` - can be used when you want to scaffolds out a new template in Sitecore or modify existing one (e.g.: to add fields or change field types)
- `jss deploy component` - scaffolds out a new component (rendering item, datasource template, and allowed placeholder settings) in Sitecore

For more details take look here: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/cli